# How to handle akka AskTimeoutException when submiting flink job

Tags: java, akka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink 1.5.3, When I submit flink job to flink cluster (on yarn), it always throw AskTimeoutException. In flink configuration file, I have configed the parmater "akka.ask.timeout=1000s" , but the Exception is still like this below.

That means I have increased the timeout parameter, "`akka.ask.timeout=1000s`" , but it does not work.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Job submission failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobSubmitHandler.lambda$handleRequest$2(JobSubmitHandler.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:770)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:83)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:603)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/dispatcher#-1851759541]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage".
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:899)
    ... 21 more

Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/dispatcher#-1851759541]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    ... 9 more
```

So is there any solution to avoid this issue?

Comment: It might not be the root cause. The timeout exceptions are sometimes thrown because the task fails, and is unable to respond to heartbeat request.

Answer (score 8):

The timeouts of the communication between the REST handlers and the Flink cluster is controlled by `web.timeout`. The timeout is specified in milliseconds and, thus, you would need to set it to `web.timeout: 1000000` in your `flink-conf.yaml` if you want to wait 1000s.

Moreover, it would be good to check the cluster entrypoint logs why the job submission takes so long. Usually it should not take longer than 10 seconds.